# How to remove items from Places sidebar in Nautilus 3.6?

Tags: 12.10, gnome, nautilus, places

I am attempting to remove bookmarks from the Places sidebar in Nautilus 3.6. Specifically, I would like to remove the "Pictures" item.

I have found answers for older versions in which one can remove or edit entries in ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs. However, this does not seem to work in 3.6. I am running Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome.

Removing things in the bookmarks menu does not seem to change anything and the option to remove by right clicking is grayed out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

You need to comment out entries in the following file:

```
~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

Comment: And how do I convert a functional line into a comment?

Comment: Using a `#`, as the explanation lines above.

Comment: Rather than commenting out the entries, I simply edited them to point to folders I actually use and want in the list (in my case, in my Dropbox). For example:
`XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Dropbox"` and `XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Dropbox/Music"` Worked great! (This was on 13.10.)

Comment: Doesn't work. Try this instead: http://askubuntu.com/a/348112/111115 (just point all entires to `$HOME` instead of `$HOME/something`). I tried commenting out; pointing them to a non-existing path, but only pointing them to $HOME removes them.

Comment: May also have to edit ```/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults``` and restart computer. See Mrnatural's [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/332339/293880) for more details.

Answer (score 10):

This answer is also something of a tutorial for newbies.
Ugh.  Just looked down.  It reformatted my nice, readable 
outline. #$!

IMHO space in File windows' "Places" sidebars is valuable.  You 
  can use them to add quick jumps to where YOU need to go 
  frequently, so I wanted to ditch some of the defaults to 
  make more room.  I decided I didn't need Music, Pictures, 
  and Videos.  The folders are still there in my home folder 
  if I need to use them.  I'm just not big on multimedia.
In Raring (13.04; with the default "Unity" desktop) I ran into 
several challenges;

- User-added "Places items can be removed using the pop-up 
   menu you get by right-clicking the item, but that option 
   is grayed out for the system's default items.
- The real answer lies in Geekdom (this is still Linux, after 
   all, although wonderfully slick nowadays.)   It involves 
   editing a couple of configuration files, but there seem 
   to be several levels of defaults that tend to restore the 
   status quo behind your back.

What I eventually had to do to accomplish my goal was:

1. edit the file at  `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

   1. save a backup copy in the same folder under a recognizably 
      altered name
   2. edit our target file

      - delete the unwanted lines
      - save the modified file
2. edit `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`

   1. `cd /etc/xdg/`
   2. `sudo cp user-dirs.defaults user-dirs.defaults.orig`  # backup copy
   3. `sudo -H gedit user-dirs.defaults`

      - delete the offending lines
      - save the modified file
3. reboot

Notes:  with added explanations for newbies...

1. it should work smoothly if you do both edits in one session, 
        but if you try to do it piecemeal starting with just 
        modifying   `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`  it won't work 
        (it'll be automatically restored) and you'll have to 
        do it again after fixing `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`.
        I know this from personal experience.  :o)
        these actions are easily performed with normal GUI 
        applications like Files and Text Editor.  `~/` is 
        shell (Terminal) shorthand for your home directory 
        (a folder in the file system: the absolute path is 
        something like  `/Home/YOURUSERNAME/`  .)

   1. not absolutely necessary, but a good habit to cultivate
   2. it should be obvious which ones, depending on what you 
       want to eliminate.  Also the first time I commented them 
       off with leading '#'s, which didn't *seem* to work initially
       due to the auto-restores, but it actually probably will work.
2. this is a tip I got from Kubuntuforums.net  It's basically 
        the same procedure as step 1, except that it's a different 
        file, and one that belongs to the system at that.
        All of these commands are entered in a Terminal window 
        following the `$` prompt.  They have to be letter-perfect,
        except that you can change the second parameter of the cp 
        command, the backup file name.

   1. the `sudo`'s are necessary because users don't have 
       security "permission" to modify these resources, so you 
       give your password when asked (you are an administrator, 
       aren't you?  Original users are by default) and proceed 
       to pretend you're "root" (the "superuser" but be careful 
       -- you could break something if you mess around.)
   2. this brings up a normal-looking instance of the Text Editor
       but with the necessary permissions so the "Save" doesn't
       fail.  Also see note 1.2.
3. the changes don't take effect until you reboot, but it's OK 
        to do what else you need to immediately do in the meantime.
4. if you ARE a newbie and you get this under your belt, 
       congratulations!  You're well on your way to Geekhood.

Comment: Could you please edit your post following [the markdown](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help)? I noticed you have several nested numbered list with references, and I don't want to mess them up.

Comment: Outlines with numberings other than numeric are not supported in markdown

Comment: Difficult to read, sure; but apart from that I wonder why this answer was downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

Open Nautilus, go to your User folder, press Control + H, to show hidden files, then open the file called with .bookmarks-gtk.
You can remove the unneeded lines from that file. 
You could also right click the menu bar, and remove them that way, but that's what I did in the past. 
Hope my answer helps.

Comment: At least in Ubuntu 13.10, that file is named `.gtk-bookmarks`, and does not contain any of the "Places" bookmarks, only ones you have made yourself.

Answer (score -2):

Right click on each item and select *Remove*! You can manage them from bookmarks menu too.

Edit: For *Places* you can delete/rename the folder from home directory. I have removed *Music* from home folder and now it is not in left list.

Comment: The remove option is grayed out. Thoughts?

Comment: Also, strangely, removing items from the bookmarks menu doesn't change the Places list.

Comment: Edited my answer ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that. I deleted the ~/Documents directory and it was recreated when I restarted. Note that I have successfully replaced those directories with symlinks, but I have not gotten rid of them altogether.

Comment: May be hardcoded in Nautilus, like the keyboard indicator not being able to be disabled at all with >1 keyboards without hex-editing the executable.