# How do I remove items from the Places section of the Files sidebar?

Tags: unity, 13.04, files, customization

I don't use the Music, Documents, Pictures, Video, and Trash folders often enough to warrant them an honorary place on the sidebar of Ubuntu's 13.04 default file manager "Files".

[image]

I would like to remove them, but the "Remove" item on the context menu is grayed out. Since Linux distros tend to be configurable I'm guessing there is a way around this.

The Gear menu doesn't seem to have any options to do this:

[image]

The *Bookmarks* menu looked helpful, but it still made no changes.

[image]

[image]

<sub>(This is after I removed all the Bookmarks I wasn't interested in.)</sub>

I have also tried the suggestion from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/152540/19047) and commented out lines I don't want from `user-dirs.dirs`, but still no luck:

```
$ vim ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
<edits>
$ xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update
```

How do you remove these default items from the sidebar?

Comment: @Arnold is perfectly right here. [This answer there](http://askubuntu.com/a/152540) is still valid and its they way to go. It still is Nautilus being responsible for files in 13.04 Ubuntu.

Comment: @Takkat I just tried that answer, it didn't change the appearance at all. Have you tried this on 13.04? Also, if Nautilus is being used for files in 13.04, why does the File->About page say "Files 3.6.3"?

Comment: I was able to fix it finally by following [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-the-nautilus-sidebar/152540#comment382550_152540) comment.

Comment: Great! I edited the answer to add the comment. This makes it more prominent ;)

Comment: @Takkat 's answer on this link perfectly works on my 13.04 x64

http://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-the-nautilus-sidebar

Answer (score 8):

The answer to this question is covered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/152540/19047).

You need to change the variables in `.config/user-dirs.dirs` to point to `$HOME` like this:

```
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME"
```

Comment: Wow, that helped. Simply deleting those entries didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Bookmarks > Edit Bookmakrs... You will find further options to remove or edit given bookmarks(i.e Documents, Music, Videos etc.).

[image]

My image represents Ubuntu 12.04.3. In your Ubuntu, if you don't find Bookmarks menu, check if it's there under Gear icon (Top right).

Comment: Unfortunately in 13.04 there is no `Edit Bookmarks` menu available from the Gear icon or the menu bar.

Comment: In 16.04, there is an option `Bookmarks` which does the same. But the changes do not affect the sidepane.